# How to correctly fetch data from xml using xslt when xml has namespace associated with elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to do some transformation using xslt, however i am facing some issues if a namespace is declared in XML file:

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/ XSD.xsd"
   xmlns="http://example.com/">

  <elem1> TEST </elem1>

</rootNode>
```

In the xsl stylesheet, i have code like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

     <TAG1>  <xsl:value-of select="elem1"/> </TAG1>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that if I don't remove the namespace in XML viz:
    xmlns="http://example.com/"

No values are getting fetched from the XML file.

I tried searching lots posts, however i didn't get any concrete clue as to what is happening. I think, somehow it might be related to namespace, that too i tried, no values are getting fetched from the XML.

Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare the namespace in XSLT. Something like this will work (note the `exclude-result-prefixes`, which prevents the new namespace binding from popping up as part of the output):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.com/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ex">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <TAG1>  <xsl:value-of select="ex:elem1"/> </TAG1>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Remember that namespace prefixes are just placeholders for the actual namespace](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-11-SECT-1.html). So even though you bind a prefix to the namespace in XSLT, it may have a different prefix (or no prefix) in other XML documents, as long as it is bound to the same namespace.

Another issue with your code is that your primary template matches the root node `/` (which is before the root element `rootNode`). So besides the fix on namespaces, you will also have to fix your XPath:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ex:rootNode/ex:elem1"/>
```

Comment: Yes that is correct; however, after this, each element gets xmlns:ex="http://example.com/" as the attribute, which means <TAG> will have like this: <TAG1 xmlns:ex="http://example.com/"> TEST </TAG1>.

Comment: @CuriousMind, no, these are not attributes, they are called namespace bindings, and technically they don't change your output (it is just uneasy on the eye). You can prevent outputting redundant namespaces by adding an `exclude-result-prefixes="ex"` to the root element of the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate a lot!